# Creating a vector in a template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector

I am trying to create a vector inside a template class where the type of the vector depends on the template of the class I am defining it in. My code is as follows :

```
template<class T>
class A {
    vector<T*> vec;
    vec.resize(100);
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error message :

```
error: ‘vec’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘getc’?
     vec.resize(100);
     ^~~
```

Can someone please tell me how to go about defining a vector like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `vec.resize(100);` has to be inside a function or a constructor. You cannot call a function directly in a class definition.

Comment: `did you mean 'getc'` is a bit weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates. This non-template code would also be an error

```
class A {
    vector<int*> vec;
    vec.resize(100);
}
```

because `vec.resize(100)` is not in a function. I guess you want that code to be called in the constructor, like this

```
class A {
    vector<int*> vec;
    A() {
        vec.resize(100);
    }
}
```

That is legal. Now we can turn that legal code into a template

```
template <class T>
class A {
    vector<T*> vec;
    A() {
        vec.resize(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I realise that idiotic mistake I made now. Thank you for the answer :).